# How to check distinct id in spec/coll-of

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

```
(s/def ::users (s/coll-of ::user :distinct true))
```

The spec above requires each user map to be distinct but How can I specify it to check for distinct `:user/ids` only

The collection bellow shouldn't be allowed:

```
[{:id 10 :name "Jessica"} {:id 10 :name "Erica"}]
```

Comment: Can you give more context? Are you trying to generate sample data? Or, are you trying to test a function? Could you just use a single map with ID as key and NAME as value? Could you generate unique IDs first, then associate random (possibly non-unique) names to each ID?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
(s/def ::id (s/int-in 0 40)) ; just for testing purposes
(s/def ::name string?)
(s/def ::user (s/and (s/keys :req-un [::id ::name])))
(s/def ::user-list (s/and
                       (s/coll-of ::user :distinct true :into [])
                       #(if (empty? %) true (apply distinct? (mapv :id %)))))

(deftest so-test
    (let [users [{:id 11 :name "Jessica"} {:id 11 :name "Erica"}]]
        (prn (g/generate (s/gen ::user-list)))
        (s/assert ::user-list users)))
```