# Spec a collection to have exactly one of each values

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

Having this map:

```
{:id 5
 :fields [{:field :a :val 1}
          {:field :c :val 3}
          {:field :b :val 2}
          {:field :d :val 4}
          ...]}
```

and separate specs for each field value like `(s/def ::field-a ...)`, `(s/def ::field-b ...)`, `(s/def ::field-c ...)`,

how should I spec it so that `:fields` in the map contains each (and exactly one) of `{:field a ...}`, `{:field b ...}`, `{:field c ...}` (disregarding order) and optionally other values?

Comment: Your question is possibly answered by this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46135111/how-to-check-distinct-id-in-spec-coll-of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is a little bit voluminous, I know, but anyways:

```
(s/def ::id int?)
(s/def ::val int?)
(s/def ::field keyword?)
(s/def ::some string?)

(s/def ::abstract-field (s/keys :req-un [::field ::val]))

(s/def ::field-a (s/and (s/keys :req-un [::field ::val]) #(= (:field %) :a)))
(s/def ::field-b (s/and (s/keys :req-un [::field ::val]) #(= (:field %) :b)))
(s/def ::field-c (s/and (s/keys :req-un [::field ::val]) #(= (:field %) :c)))
(s/def ::field-d (s/and (s/keys :req-un [::field ::val]) #(= (:field %) :d)))

(s/def ::fields (s/and
                    (s/+ (s/alt :required (s/or :a ::field-a
                                                :b ::field-b
                                                :c ::field-c
                                                :d ::field-d)
                                :rest ::abstract-field))
                    (fn [x] (= [:a :b :c :d]
                               (into [] (sort (map (comp first second) (filter #(= :required (first %)) x))))))))

(let [x1 [{:field :b :val 2}
          {:field :a :val 1}
          ;{:field :a :val 1}
          {:field :d :val 4}
          {:field :e :val 4}
          {:field :c :val 3}
          ]]
    (s/explain ::fields x1)
    (s/conform ::fields x1))
```

Comment: Damn, that's one big spec! :D I was hoping for some concise solution, but I guess there's no other way around it. Thank you very much!